# Remove a package from within DrRacket

Tags: racket, package, package-managers

In the command line, I can add and remove packages with `raco pkg`. In DrRacket, however, package management is handled through either `File -> Install Package` (if you are only installing packages), or `File -> Package Manager` (if you want to install a package, get a list of installed packages, etc.).

Unfortunately, this dialog does not appear to have a tag for removing a package. Is it possible to remove a package from DrRacket, or must that be done with with:

```
raco pkg remove <package-name>
```

Obviously, I can do it indirectly from within Racket using `find-exe`:

```
#lang racket
(require compiler/find-exe)
(system* "-l" "raco" "remove" "<package-name>")
```

But this seems clunky. Is there a better way to remove packages with DrRacket/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a package by going to: `File -> Package Manager`, and click on the second tab (`Currently Installed`) to see a list of all of your installed packages. Select the package you want to remove, and you will find a remove button in the bottom right corner. If you click that button the package will be removed from your system.

Here is a picture of the list of currently installed packages with the remove button highlighted.

[image]